# Same user name in different databases with different logins

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server there are 3 databases; `db1`, `db2`, and `db3`. I also have 3 logins; `login1`, `login2`, and `login3`.

In `db1` , there is a `USER` called `testUser` which is mapped to `login1`. On `db2`, there is also a `USER` called `testUser` which is mapped to `login2`. Finally, in `db3`, the is also a `USER`, `testUser`, which is mapped to `login3`.

I'm unable to connect `db1` with `testUser` and `login1`

I just use the connecting string as below:

```
var dbConnection = string.Format("Data Source='{0}';Initial Catalog='{1}';User ID={2};Password='{3}';MultipleActiveResultSets=TRUE;Connection Timeout=60;Max Pool Size=5000;Pooling=TRUE", SqlServer, DBname, Username, Password);
```

USERNAME is `testUser` , DBname is `db1` and Password is login1 's password.

Comment: Help you what, here? What's the problem? A `USER` doesn't *have* to be mapped to a `LOGIN` with the same name. `CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN Gobbledeegock_tralalala;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: Hi, I have one sqlserver, in the sql server, there is 3 dbs from "db1","db2" to "db3", I also have 3 logins from "login1", "login2" to "login3", in db1 , there is a user called "testUser" which is mapped into "login1", in db2, there is also a user called "testUser" which is mapped into "login2", in db3, the "testUser" is mapped into "login3". But when I use the "testUser" and login1's password to connect db1, I cannot login the database.

Comment: You don't login a `testUser` you would log in as `Login1`. Show us what your trying, and the errors you're getting, including those logged in the logs.

Comment: [edit] your question, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: *"USERNAME is `testUser`"* There's your problem. As I said in the above comment: "**You don't login as `testUser`** you would log in as `Login1`".

Comment: If you were using database users as the authentication object, then the database would need to be a contained database; which means the `USER` would not be mapped to a `LOGIN`.

Comment: To restate what @Larnu is saying, to use a user mapped to a login, you authenticate at the instance level by specifying the login (login1) and password in the connection string. The database user (testuser) is used only for authorization (i.e. grant object permissions to the database user) and not specified directly in the application. I suggest you make the login and user names the same to avoid confusion.